# How to build a php website to upload video using mobile browser?

Tags: php, upload

Is it possible to record and upload photo/video from a phone into a website using mobile browser? I work with pHp. How do i go about it if possible. (I use Chrome browser in an Android Phone.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server-side code makes no difference.  It entirely depends on how to access the video capabilities of the platform (if they exist) in client-side code.  In this case, you're probably going to be specifically targeting HTML5.

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) looks like a great place to start.

With HTML5 you can use `input type="file"` to access device capabilities (assuming they exist and the user allows it), such as:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

To build something truly cross-platform with graceful degradation there is of course a lot more to it.  But the basic idea is to use the `input` to capture the media.